# Query failed due to LIMIT error in redshift merge query

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I was just trying to run one merge statement redshift, But continuously I am getting `"ERROR: syntax error at or near "limit" Position: 229"`. But no where in code I have used this `"limit"` key word. Even inside SELECT query is also running fine separately.

Can anyone please help me to understand why this error I am getting.

**QUERY:**

```
MERGE INTO dim_containers trgt
      USING (SELECT s.ip_container_id,
                    s.name,
                    s.created_by,
                      s.creation_date,
                    s.last_update_date,
                    s.last_updated_by,
                    decode(s.tp,'C', 'CONTAINER',
                                'T', 'TRAY',
                                s.tp)
                           container_type
              FROM   TBL_CONTAINER_TYPES     s) src
      ON (src.ip_container_id = dim_containers.ip_container_id)
      WHEN matched THEN UPDATE SET
         description            = src.NAME,
         container_type         = src.container_type,
         created_by             = src.created_by,
         creation_date          = src.creation_date,
         last_update_date       = src.last_update_date,
         last_updated_by        = src.last_updated_by,
         local_last_update_date = lv_sysdate,
         local_last_updated_by  = lc_user
      WHEN NOT matched THEN INSERT
        
      VALUES
       ((CASE WHEN src.ip_container_id = -1
                 THEN 0
              WHEN src.ip_container_id = -2
                 THEN 1
              ELSE scty_seq.NEXTVAL
         END),
         src.NAME,
         src.container_type,
         src.creation_date,
         src.created_by,
         src.last_update_date,
         src.last_updated_by,
         src.ip_container_id,
         lv_sysdate,
         lc_user);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a subquery as the source table.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_MERGE.html

Which states "source_table can't be a view or a subquery."

As to the error message my best guess is that either there is a view involved, the query compiler is trying to rewrite your statement to not need the subquery and failing, or Redshift is just confused.

You should be able to remove the subquery and move the decode to the WHEN MATCHED clause.  However, it is required that "Rows in target_table can't match multiple rows in source_table."